# Understanding embedding vectors dimension

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, nlp, recurrent-neural-network

In deep learning, in particularly NLP, words are transformed into a vector representation to be fed into a neural network such as an RNN. By referring to the link:

http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-07-NLP-RNNs-Representations/#Word%20Embeddings

In the section of Word Embeddings, it is said that:

> A word embedding W:words→Rn is a paramaterized function mapping words
>   in 
>       some language to high-dimensional vectors (perhaps 200 to 500 dimensions)

I do not understand the **purpose of the dimension of the vectors**. What does it mean to have a **vector of 200 dimensions** compared to a **vector of 20 dimensions**?

Does it improve the overall accuracy of the model? Could anyone give me a simple example regarding the choice of dimension of the vectors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These word embeddings also called Distributed Word Embedding is based on

> you know a word by the company it keeps

as quoted by  [John Rupert Firth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Rupert_Firth)

So we know the meaning of a word by its context. You can think of each scalar in the vector (of a word) represents its strength for a concept. This slide from [Prof. Pawan Goyal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=280&v=e_lJNzOaQY4) explains it all.

[image]

So you want good vector size to capture decent amount of concepts but you do not want a too huge vector because it will then become the bottleneck in training of models where these embeddings are used.

Also the vector size is mostly fixed as most do not train their own embedding but rather use openly available embeddings as they are trained for many hours on huge data. So using them will force us to use an embedding layers with dimensions as given by the openly available embedding you are using (word2vec, glove etc)

Distributed Word Embeddings is a major milestone in the area of  deep learning in NLP. They give better accuracy as compared of tfidf based embeddings.

Comment: So in the way, it is represented where Royalty has a vector of [0.99,0.99,0.02,0.98] which is dimension 4, based on the slide?

Comment: The vector of `king` is representation of 0.99 royality, 0.99 mulculinity, 0.05 faminity and so on. Basically each dimension in the vector represents the strength of  some concept (roality, mulculinity, faminity etc). However these concepts are hidden and we cant really interpret them. But that's their hidden meaning.

Comment: Nice explanation! Do you know what is the dimensionality in Word2vec?